# Host Wcf service in windows service which runs for every 1minute to move files from one folder to another using timer

Tags: c#

I have a wcf service which implements some logice like. I want to move all the files from source folder to destination folder for every 1 minute if new files are added in source folder.My service converts files to Pdf files

How to use threading if i want to move 100 files at a time and each file is of 1 MB size.

Comment: I want to use this wcf service as a windows service

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound like a WCF service - where do you have the web service / communication component in your logic?

This sounds more like a little console app (to move the files) that you should set up using the Windows scheduler to run every minute.